# D3 brushing and stroking question in both the x and y axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, visualization

I have plagiarized some code from bl.ocks.org to create a working example of my desired chart, but I am now stumbling on the last step.  I have a Gantt style chart that I would like to navigate in both the x and the y dimension.  From the code provided below you can see I've managed to recreate the X brush and zoom, but would now like to add the Y brush and zoom. Similar to the navigation done in this example:

https://www.visualcinnamon.com/2016/07/brush-bar-chart-d3

The issue that I think I'm facing is that I need to duplicate the navigation elements onto the Y axis, but somehow make them independently controlled.  Has anyone ever tried this or seen a working example?

My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<style>

.zoom {
  cursor: move;
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.dot {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

</style>
<head>
  <title></title>
 </head>

<body>

<svg width="1200" height="500"></svg>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)
var tasklist = []
const d = new Date()
var e

for (i=0; i< 10; i++){
   e = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)
   tasklist.push({
    "TASKSTARTTIME": d.getTime() + i * Math.floor(Math.random()*1000) ,
    "ELAPSED": e,
    "name": i,
    "TASKENDTIME": d.getTime() + Number(e)
  })
}

//==============================================================================================================;
//==============================================================================================================;
//==============================================================================================================;

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 110, left: 180},
    margin2 = {top: +svg.attr("height")-80, right: margin.right, bottom: 30, left: margin.left},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = +svg.attr("height") - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%b %Y");

var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    x2 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleBand().range([0, height]),
    y2 = d3.scaleBand().range([0, height2]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x),
    xAxis2 = d3.axisBottom(x2),
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

var brush = d3.brushX()
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height2]])
    .on("brush end", brushed);

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
    .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "zoom")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(zoom);

var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var context = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "context")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

//------------------------------------;

  x.domain(d3.extent([].concat(tasklist.map(d => d.TASKSTARTTIME), tasklist.map(d => d.TASKENDTIME))));
  y.domain(tasklist.map(d => d.name));
  x2.domain(x.domain());
  y2.domain(y.domain());

  focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  focus.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(yAxis);

  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
      .call(xAxis2);

  context.append("g")
      .attr("class", "brush")
      .call(brush)
      .call(brush.move, x.range());

  focus.selectAll(".dot")
                       .data(tasklist)
                       .enter()
                       .append("circle")
                       .attr("class", "dot")
                       .style("stroke", "black")
                       .style("clip-path", "url(#clip)")                       
                       .attr("r", "2")
                       .attr("cx", d => x(d.TASKSTARTTIME))
                       .attr("cy", d => y(d.name) + y.bandwidth()/2)
                     ;//  .call(d3.helper.tooltip());

   focus.selectAll(".rect")
                       .data(tasklist)
                       .enter()
                       .append("rect")
                       .attr("class", "rect")
                       .style("stroke", "black")
                       .style("clip-path", "url(#clip)")                       
                       .attr("height", "3")
                       .attr("width", d => d.ELAPSED)
                       .attr("x", d => x(d.TASKSTARTTIME))
                       .attr("y", d => y(d.name) + y.bandwidth()/2)
                     ;//  .call(d3.helper.tooltip());                     

  context.selectAll(".dot2")
                       .data(tasklist)
                       .enter()
                       .append("circle")
                       .attr("class", "dot2 axis--x")
                       .attr("stroke", "black")
                       .style("clip-path", "url(#clip)")                       
                       .attr("r", "0.1")
                       .attr("cx", d => x(d.TASKSTARTTIME))
                       .attr("cy", d => y2(d.name) + y.bandwidth()/2)

  context.selectAll(".rect")
                       .data(tasklist)
                       .enter()
                       .append("rect")
                       .attr("class", "rect")
                       .style("stroke", "black")
                       .style("clip-path", "url(#clip)")                       
                       .attr("height", "3")
                       .attr("width", d => d.ELAPSED)
                       .attr("x", d => x(d.TASKSTARTTIME))
                       .attr("y", d => y2(d.name))         

//-----------------------------------------;

function brushed() {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return; // ignore brush-by-zoom
  var s = d3.event.selection || x2.range();
  x.domain(s.map(x2.invert, x2));

  svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
      .scale(width / (s[1] - s[0]))
      .translate(-s[0], 0));
  focus.selectAll(".dot")
       .attr("cx", d => x(d.TASKSTARTTIME)); 
  focus.selectAll(".rect")
       .attr("x", d => x(d.TASKSTARTTIME)); 
  focus.select("g.axis--x").call(xAxis);
}

function zoomed() {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return; // ignore zoom-by-brush
  var t = d3.event.transform;
  //debugger
  x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());
  context.select(".brush").call(brush.move, x.range().map(t.invertX, t));
  focus.selectAll(".dot")
       .attr("cx", d => x(d.TASKSTARTTIME)); 
  focus.selectAll(".rect")
       .attr("x", d => x(d.TASKSTARTTIME))
       .attr("width", d => d.ELAPSED*t.k); 
  focus.select("g.axis--x").call(xAxis);
}

function ObjectLength( object ) {
    var length = 0;
    for( var key in object ) {
        if( object.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
            ++length;
        }
    }
    return length;
};


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can have as many brush areas as you want, just duplicate the `focus` logic of the x-axis for the y-axis and use a `d3.brushY()`, have a look at `parallel coordinate` examples

Comment: I'm not sure we're talking about the same thing.  Do you mean this? https://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/1341281

Comment: it is an example of using multiple brushes, if they are brushX or brushY or combos is not relevant, just how to program them.